# Bluez5.42 with Linux 3.8

Tags: c++, linux-kernel, beagleboneblack, openwrt, bluez

I have been developing a BLE application for `openwrt` on `beaglebone black`. Earlier, i was using Linux 4.4.14 for openwrt and i have successfully created BLE application (without using `dbus`) in `C++` programming language. I can advertise, connect, bond, and can do all sort of operations.

I am now planning to switch to Linux 3.18 (as it is marked as stable for beaglebone black) and i want to use dbus for my BLE application.

Is there any dependency between `Linux` version and bluez stack version?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no straight mapping between kernel version and BlueZ version. But with BlueZ 5.x (management interface) in place Linux kernel (management interface is available from Linux Kernel 3.4) and BlueZ library should work.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against 3.8. That's an ancient kernel. Development has progressed well beyond that and left it behind. 4.4 and 4.9 are current stable kernels and also used by the reference debian images: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian#Kernel_Options

Comment: Do you have this project in github?  I am trying to work with Bluez on RPi3, and have been having difficulties getting it working reliably for GATT server.

Comment: @Michael: No. But i will soon make it public when i have stable API. You can ask questions and if i knew the answer, i will surely comment.

Comment: @abhiarora Thank you, I will post my questions.  I look forward to your API as well.